# Total price didn't show up in shopping cart in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a shopping cart page which the total price didn't show up in the table the products added (picture below). I can't figure out where's the error. I need help, thanks in advance!

[image]

Here's my code:

example.php

```
<?php include("dbconnection.php");?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Meal</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:60%;">
        <h2 align="center">SoftAOX Tutorial | Creating an Online Shopping Cart in PHP & Mysql</h2>
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM meal ORDER BY meal_id ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <form method="post" action="shop.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["meal_id"]; ?>">
                            <div style="border: 1px solid #eaeaec; margin: -1px 19px 3px -1px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05); padding:10px;" align="center">
                                <img src="<?php echo $row["meal_image_Upload"]; ?>" class="img-responsive">
                                <h5 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["meal_name"]; ?></h5>
                                <h5 class="text-danger">$ <?php echo $row["meal_price"]; ?></h5>
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["meal_name"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["meal_price"]; ?>">
                                <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-default" value="Add to Bag">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <h2>My Shopping Bag</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th width="40%">Product Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
                    <th width="20%">Price Details</th>
                    <th width="15%">Order Total</th>
                    <th width="5%">Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values) {
                ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $values["product_price"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo number_format(($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]), 2); ?></td>
                                <td><a href="shop.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["product_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">X</span></a></td>
                            </tr>
                <?php 
                            $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]);
                        }
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>
                            <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

shop.php

```
<?php
       include("dbconnection.php"); 

       if(isset($_POST["add"])) {
           if(isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {
               $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "product_id");
               if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
                   $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
                   $item_array = array(
                       'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
                       'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                       'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                       'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
                   );
                   $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
                   echo '<script>window.location="example.php"</script>';
               } else {
                   echo '<script>alert("Products already added to cart")</script>';
                   echo '<script>window.location="example.php"</script>';
               }
           } else {
                   $item_array = array(
                       'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
                       'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                       'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                       'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
                   );
                   $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
           }
       }
       if(isset($_GET["action"])) {
           if($_GET["action"] == "delete") {
               foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values) {
                   if($values["product_id"] == $_GET["id"]) {
                       unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
                       echo '<script>alert("Product has been removed")</script>';
                       echo '<script>window.location="example.php"</script>';
                   }
               }
           }
       }
  ?>
```

Comment: check my ans and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out the float no from product price, consider using regex. 
This is the way u could do it

```
 $productprice = "RM6.90";
 preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $productprice, $matches);
 $floatproductprice = (float)$matches[0];// it will contain the float value
```

$floatproductprice should be used to calculate the total and also this value
should be stored in the database. Also change the type of price details and order total in database to Float or Double.

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea but I'm quite blur on how to apply this when the product price being captured from the database because I set the product price attribute as "text". Sorry, I'm still learning and this is for my final year project.

Comment: @znf96, i have edited my ans. Hope this solves any doubts u have.

Comment: @znf96, plz accept it as the ans if it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

Your product price is RM6.90. Give only numbers to multiply.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by that? @premi

Comment: @znf96, he is telling you that RM6.90 is a string and you cannot multiply strings

Answer (score 1):

Your product price appears to have the literal "RM" in it as a suffix. This will cause PHP to abort number processing treating values as zeros.

You must remove non-numeric characters from your strings to make them true numbers.  Something like the following may help. Kind of ugly, but simple use.

```
$capture_prefix = "";       #prefix for last number
function capture_number( $text )
{
    global $capture_prefix;
    $number = preg_replace( '/^[^\d]+/', "", $text );
    $capture_prefix = substr( $text, 0, strlen($text) - strlen($number) );
    return $number;
}
```

Comment: Even better: remember the suffix so you can insert it before the values you print.

Comment: This is because I set the price attribute in the database as "text" so the "RM" was captured from the database. Is there any other way I can change the php code instead of change the attribute type? @Gilbert

Comment: Edited answer to include sample function.